# Anchor tag server Side Click Event in IE10

Tags: asp.net, anchor, internet-explorer-10

I have anchor tag in my application and server side click event for that. 
When i open it in IE10 click event is not working .

Here is my code

```
   <a id="lnkReports" class="mainbtns-link" style="text-align: left" runat="server">
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Style="text-transform: capitalize" 
Text="REPORTS"></asp:Label>
```

Server Side Code

lnkReports.ServerClick += new EventHandler(lnkReports_ServerClick);

void lnkReports_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           lbltext.Text="Sample";
        }

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [LinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
  <asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" 
       Text="Click Me" 
       Font-Names="Verdana" 
       Font-Size="14pt" 
       OnClick="LinkButton_Click" 
       runat="server"/>
```

CS Code

```
  void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {
     lbltext.Text="You clicked the link button";
  }
```